# How do I sort the files by name?

Tags: apache-nifi

Can NiFi sort the retrieved files by filename?

I'm trying to use the EnforceOrder processor but cannot figure this out.
There are no questions in this forum on something as basic as 'sort by filename' 'sort by file name'.

I'm using a ***GetFile*** to pull in *.json files.
I'm just looking into how to do some basic things such as sort by name, if filename contains a date then sort by that file name converted to a date, sort by actual date of file, group by regexp and then sort etc.

*Update*
I've tried to use the "UpdateAttribute" to carry through the file name and specify that as the initial order but that is invalid as it is not a number.

I've tried to also use the file.lastModifiedTime in the Initial Order but that fails too.

How do you sort the files by their name?

Comment: check prioritization on queue level: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#settings

Comment: or this processor: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.17.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EnforceOrder/index.html